# Trying to configure jmxeval plugin to Nagwin

Tags: jmx, nagios

I get this respond from CMD after checking the jmxeval plugin during setting up,

Command: check_jmxeval.bat

CMD output:

```
C:\Nagwin_x64\plugins>check_jmxeval.bat
org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: Argument "<filename>" is required


at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.parseArgument(CmdLineParser.java:448)
at com.adahas.tools.jmxeval.App.execute(App.java:43)
at com.adahas.tools.jmxeval.App.main(App.java:110)


Argument "<filename>" is required
java -jar jmxeval.jar  <filename> [--schema <version>] [--set (--define) <name=value>] [--validate <boolean>]
--schema <version>            : set schema version
--set (--define) <name=value> : set variable name to value
--validate <boolean>          : set validation true|false, default is   false
```

I am following the steps in google code project: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jmxeval/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki

Comment: does this mean that there is a problem in java classes?

Comment: There was a bug in the version you've been using which prints the exception trace which it shouldn't have.

@clagio's answer is correct, you need to specify a filename that defines the checks need to run. Please have a read of https://github.com/venushka/jmxeval for how to create a file that defines checks or pick a sample check file included in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

```
Argument "<filename>" is required
```

You need to pass as argument to the script the path to the xml file containing the instructions on what to check